# how get page start records from 23000 to 23004 in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pagination

I have an elasticsearch database contain about 100k rows. I want paginate about 30k rows.

The error that I get is about max-result-window.

In this case I cannot get records from 23000 to 23004 because is exceeds 10k records. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd need to paginate to records 23000-23004? ES is a **search** engine and not a database where you can scan your "tables" with cursors, so you should first issue a search query to reduce the result set as much as possible and then paginate on the results.

Comment: Because I want to show a dataset to user in html page. This dataset has 100k records. I want that user can jump to page 827 to see last records. I can try with scroll api but it is maybe not efficient. I can scroll by size 4, until at calcutate record page example page 110 * 4 = 440, so scroll, then scroll, then scroll jump to 440 - 444. Can be it a solution?

Comment: The Scroll API should not be used for paginating back and forth in real time, you should prefer [`search_after` with a PIT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround that I find is to use scroll api.
In pratice I scroll by size 20 (1 page), until I achieve page 51711. It takes about 10 minutes because It scroll all data before achieve start record 1070100 to record 1070120.

```
url = "http://localhost:9200"
index = "civile"
pageLimit = 20

bodyPageAllDocBil = {"query": {"bool": {"must": [], "should": []}}, "_source": ["annoruolo", "annosentenza",  "cf_giudice","codiceoggetto", "controparte", "gradogiudizio", "nomegiudice", "parte","distretto"]}

bodyCountAllDoc = bodyPageAllDocBil
bodyCountAllDoc.pop('_source', None)
es = Elasticsearch(url)
res = es.count(index=index, body=bodyCountAllDoc) 
sizeCount = res["count"]

bodyPageAllDocs = bodyPageAllDocBil
bodyPageAllDocs["size"] = pageLimit
es = Elasticsearch(url)

docs = es.search(index=index, body=bodyPageAllDocs,scroll = '10m')

currentSize = pageLimit
scrollId = docs["_scroll_id"]
page = 51711
paginationStart = (page - 1) * pageLimit

while currentSize <= paginationStart + pageLimit:
    es = Elasticsearch(url)
    docs = es.scroll(scroll_id = scrollId,scroll = '10m')
    countRec = len(docs["hits"]["hits"])
    
    if currentSize == paginationStart:
        print(docs["hits"]["hits"][0])
        print(docs["hits"]["hits"][1])
        #...

    currentSize = currentSize + countRec
    scrollId = docs['_scroll_id']
```